# core-plot and navigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, core-plot

I am using core-plot sdk and trying to plot a bar chart.

I have RootViewController which extends from UINavigationController, and I am adding my viewController which render the barChart, here is code

RootViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   barChartViewController = [[BarChartViewController alloc]init];
   [self pushViewController:barChartViewController animated:NO];
}
```

BarChartViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.title =@"BarChart";
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.4 green: 0.8 blue:0 alpha:1];

   self.navigationItem.title = @"BarChart";
    // and then creating the barchart and rendering it, which works fine.
}
```

Here the navigationBar doesn't appear and so is the title for navigationBar.
And then the following code from BarChartViewController.m

```
-(void)barPlot:(CPBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
   NSLog(@"barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex %d", index);
   DetailViewController *detailViewController =  
       [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:
          [NSBundle mainBundle]];

   [self.navigationController pushViewController: detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

So in the above code what I am trying to do is once user selects a bar from the barChart (which is getting displayed properly), the above method gets invoked, i do see on the console the log message is getting displayed telling which barChart was selected, but the controller is not going to DetailViewController, which I am pushing here.

So as you can see I am facing two problems with the code one the navigation bar is not appearing and another one I am not able to push a new viewController to navigationController. I am guessing there is some issue with the core-plot and navigation controller.

Please help.

Thanks,
Yogesh